How Connect Tkinter With django using zerorpc?
i have tkinter app want connect and send data to django project using zerorpc
on local host its work nice but after deploy django on ubuntu server with gunicorn & nginx and open port 4242 on ufw still dosen't work.
when i check gunicorn status i get error on:
Exception in thread Thread-l (verificate):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File'/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py',line 1075, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
    File'/usr/lib/python3.12/threading.py',line 1012, in run
     self._target(*self._agrs, **self._kwargs)
    File '_zmq',line 732, in zmq.backend.cython._zmq.Socket.set
 TypeError: set() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)

i bind django gunicorn and nginx pass proxy on address: 0.0.0.0:8000
i try also bind  django gunicorn and nginx pass proxy on address: 127.0.0.1:8000
i use zerorpc python module on python tkinter and django
app tkinter client connect django using zerorpc on address: connect('tcp://serverip:4242')
django has function to listen on port 4242 but i use thread module to run this function with django views in sametime.
i open port 8000 and 4242 and 80 and 443 and tcp and nginx full
